# How to use xinput to configure multiple devices with a script?

Tags: linux, xorg, mouse, xinput

How do you configure xinput to set multiple devices automatically using a script?

```
    $ xinput --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint                  id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ALPS PS/2 Device                          id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Corsair Corsair M65 Gaming Mouse          id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Corsair Corsair M65 Gaming Mouse          id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_HD               id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Corsair Corsair M65 Gaming Mouse          id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

And the problem is both of these "corsair gaming mouse" have different IDs every time. I don't know why there are two mouses... but that's the world I live in. How do I write a script to set the properties on both of them? I used this, but it didn't work the next time I booted (ID changed):

```
#!/bin/sh
xinput --set-pr
op 10 "Device Accel Profile" 6
xinput --set-prop 10 "Device Accel Velocity Scaling" 5
xinput --set-prop 10 "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 3
#xinput --set-prop 10 "Device Accel Velocity Tracker Count" 2
```

I had tried using the name, but it complains there are multiple matching devices.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There are multiple instances because your mouse if capable of having different "profiles". For example, I have a profile for CS:GO and a profile for normal computer usage. Each has profile has different polling and sensitivity etc..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are need to make changes to both you can use loop

```
#!/bin/sh
for id in $(xinput --list | \
            sed -n '/Corsair Corsair M65 Gaming Mouse.*pointer/s/.*=\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/p')
do
  xinput --set-prop $id "Device Accel Profile" 6
  ...
  whatever you want to do
  ...
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "pointer:" or "keyboard:" in front of the name. For example

```
xinput list-props 'pointer:Logitech M585/M590'
xinput list-props 'keyboard:Logitech M585/M590'
```

Comment: This doesn't work when there are multiple devices of same type and name (as in the example given above). It fails with:

    Warning: There are multiple devices matching 'pointer:...'.